# Google Analytics Not Providing Google Traffic Keywords

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search

Why Google analytics not tracking my organic google keywords and can track other search engines like bing, yahoo, etc?
screenshot: http://prnt.sc/n60ahn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's **real time traffic(or live traffic)**. Google Analytic gather keyword(query) information from search console data, that's why they first suggest to link your search console account to Google analytic. As per [this article it can take 48 hours](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1308621?hl=en) to get data from search console to analytic.  So you can directly check your search console data for fresh information, but again it is not real time, you've to wait for 3-4 days to know the query information, then it will appear in search console as well.

Comment: Oh i see, you right. thanks for the info!